Mocking graphql-request with vitest
I have been trying to mock my graphql-request with vitest. The request looks this way:
    const getTastyFruit = gql`
    query Fruit($id: String!) {
      fruit(id: $id) {
        shop {
          shopId
        }
      }
    }
  `;

This request is part of a bigger picture. Let's go top down. I have a lambda, which sits on an API Gateway Endpoint. This lambda calls a TropicalWorld client. This client has plenty of methods, one of those: CheckIfFruitIsReallyTasty. It's a private async methof of my TropicalWorld class (client).
CheckIfFruitIsReallyTasty initialises a new graphql client.
const fruitsClient = new GraphQLClient(
      "https://www.tastyfruits.com",
      { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } },
    );

Then my query comes in play:
const getTastyFruit = gql`
        query Fruit($id: String!) {
          fruit(id: $id) {
            shop {
              shopId
            }
          }
        }
      `;

Then there is a try catch block which basically awats a response from the query:
const response= await fruitsClient.request(getTastyFruit, {
        id,
      });

I was really trying different approaches, to mock this graphql requiest with vitest, but whatever I do, I get the error ERROR status code: 404, status text: undefined
vi.mock('graphql-request', () => ({

  GraphQLClient: class {
    request = vi.fn(); 
  },
  gql: (text: string) => text,
}));

This indicates, that my client still makes requests to the graphql server. The only thing I am really interested in is the repsonse, whoch I really wish to mock, so I can test happy path and the error path. But as I said, vitest graphql mocking isn't really working for me. Any ideas?

The Error came from a different place in my test code. Generally I found a great way to mock graphql in the official vitest documentation. I had to install msw for this though...
import { afterAll, afterEach, beforeAll } from 'vitest'
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node'
import { HttpResponse, graphql, http } from 'msw'

const posts = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'first post title',
    body: 'first post body',
  },
  // ...
]

export const restHandlers = [
  http.get('https://rest-endpoint.example/path/to/posts', () => {
    return HttpResponse.json(posts)
  }),
]

const graphqlHandlers = [
  graphql.query('ListPosts', () => {
    return HttpResponse.json(
      {
        data: { posts },
      },
    )
  }),
]

const server = setupServer(...restHandlers, ...graphqlHandlers)

// Start server before all tests
beforeAll(() => server.listen({ onUnhandledRequest: 'error' }))

//  Close server after all tests
afterAll(() => server.close())

// Reset handlers after each test `important for test isolation`
afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers())

here is the link
